# How to value cash as a call option?

Tags: call-options

Recently came across [this](https://www.businessinsider.com/cash-as-a-call-option-2012-9) article regarding Warren Buffett's biographer from 2012:

> “This is one of the most important things I learned from him: the optionality of cash. He thinks of cash as a call option with no expiration date, an option on every asset class, with no strike price.”

So my question is: How can one / what would be the proper way to specifically value a dollar in cash as a call option?

Comment: Cash is cash with which you are free to do with as you wish, including whatever Buffett wants to pretend that it is.

Comment: An example of quantifying the option value of cash can be found here (but am still in the process of trying to fully understand it and the exact valuation formulas ATM): https://academic.oup.com/rof/article/17/5/1649/1581144?login=false#123770505

Comment: This may be relevant in the word of academia but in the world of investing, it's just gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Black-Scholes [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model), we can see that $100 as a call option described by Buffett is worth $100. I used the current Treasury bill rate of 0.16%, a dividend rate and volatility of 0, and 10,000 years to approximate an expiration date of 'never'.

https://goodcalculators.com/black-scholes-calculator/

[image: A screenshot of a Black-Scholes calculation]

Comment: Never thought I’d get a good guffaw out of a Black-Scholes computation.

Comment: Here a little bit of something that makes me think that -- under the right conditions -- $1 in cash can be worth more than $1 when viewed as a call option (still need to read through / interpret it in detail): https://academic.oup.com/rof/article/17/5/1649/1581144?login=false#123770505

Answer (score 2):

If you hold cash (as an investor) you can do one of two things, keep it as cash or buy something with it. If you buy something (invest it), the value of that asset is driven by the market and is out of your control. It might go up in value, but it might also go down.

If you keep it, you have the *option* to buy that thing later *if* it drops in value.

That fits with Buffett's mentality of being a value investor - buying things when they are cheap. It's not a *perfect* analogy, but it helps to illustrate the power of holding cash in order to take advantage of downturns rather than being a victim of them. It also help to see that holding cash, that does not *directly* produce income, can enable the *opportunity* for income by scooping up "cheap" investments.

This is explained in the paragraphs after the one you quoted:

> It is a pretty fundamental insight. Because once an investor looks at cash as an option – in essence, the price of being able to scoop up a bargain when it becomes available – it is less tempting to be bothered by the fact that in the short term, it earns almost nothing.
>
> Suddenly, an investor’s asset allocation decisions are not simply between earning nothing in cash and earning something in bonds or stocks. The key question becomes: How much can the cash earn if I have it when I need it to buy other assets that are cheap, versus the upfront cost of holding it?”

Can you place a *monetary* value on that option? Probably not (in reality, cash is only worth its face value), but Buffett isn't one to use *quantitative measures* as much as *qualitative* ones. So I don't think he's talking about an *analytic* measure of cash - I think he's saying that cash can have value (a "negative opportunity cost" if you will) over its face value.

Comment: Great answer. Spelling is "Buffett" like Warren's friend, Jimmy Buffett. http://www.banderasnews.com/0505/nz-buffetts.htm

Comment: @OrangeCoast-reinstateMonica Here a little bit of something that makes me think that -- when making certain considerations -- $1 in cash when viewed as a call option *can indeed* have some kind of quantifiable value (still need to read through / interpret it in detail): https://academic.oup.com/rof/article/17/5/1649/1581144?login=false#123770505